# Importing Excel (.xls) into SQL using Wizard

Tags: sql, excel, sql-server-2014

Morning,

I have an interesting problem, which I'm hoping someone will be able to explain to me?

I have an excel file (.xls) with a column of order numbers some rows are blank others are populated. The order numbers are all numbers with five characters to each order number and have no A-Z's or special characters. Once I've imported this file into SQL using the wizard, the entire column is showing as NULL. I'm using nvarchar when importing the column into SQL.

From the Import Wizard I choose Microsoft Excel as the Data Source and Excel version is 97-2003. Next, for the destination I use SQL Server Native Client 11.0. Next window, 'Copy data from one or more tables of views'. I then select the table I want to import and 'Preview' the data. Here I don't see any order numbers, I only see blank spaces against items which should have an order number.

I finish the import without any errors and everything is imported with no errors or warnings. In the Order No column everything is showing as 'NULL'

Any ideas or explanations?

I'm using SQL Server 2014 Management Studio.

Thanks for your time.

PW.

Comment: Show part of the xls file and the table definition of the destination on the sql server. That will help us exclude any type errors first.

Comment: This is the IMEX issue which has existed for a long time and never been fixed. Do a bit of a search on IMEX